# How to detect gcc compile -wrap flag using macro?

Tags: gcc, macros, compiler-flags

How can I use macros in C to detect if the wrapping functions flag `-Wl,--wrap` is used during compilation by `gcc`. I would like to get something similar to

```
#ifdef WRAP_FLAG
do_something();
#endif
```